# Get columns from resultset of stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is their any way to get the specific columns from the result set of stored procedure

eg `SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM EXEC SP_NAME`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to SELECT * INTO \[temp table\] FROM \[stored procedure\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/653714/11683)

Comment: already saw these links, none of them help to solve my problem

Comment: `select col1, col2 from openrowset(...)` solves your problem. It is mentioned in the links.

Comment: plz can u provide full syntax

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (using the self-linked server trick):

```
Select * 
from openquery(
   MyLocalServer, 'exec mydbo.dbo.myStoredProc @Param=1'
)
```

Comment: what is `MyLocalServer` a string?

Comment: To use openquery command you ill need a linked server that string is a link from local server to itself. http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188427.aspx

Comment: Add a linked server. http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190479.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do some thing like this

```
create table #temp (temp_table_Schema_as_output_from_Stored_procedue)
insert into #temp
exec SP_NAME @parameters 

select COL1,COL2 from #temp
```